# Flexbox in Chrome, adding scrollbars, why?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If I run this in Firefox or IE, I get a nice fullscreen layout with no scrollbars in the browser, however in Chrome, I get a vertical scrollbar which is adding the height of the top (green) row to the layout twice:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height:100%;width:100%">
  <head>
    <style media="screen" type="text/css">
      * {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
      }
    </style>
 
  </head>

  <body style="height:100%;width:100%">
   <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column; background-color:red; height:100%">
      <div style="flex 0 0 auto; background-color:green;  min-height:200px">a</div>
      <div style="flex 1; background-color:yellow; height:100%;width:100%; display:flex; flex-direction:row">
          <div style="flex 1; background-color:purple; height:100%;width:100%">a</div>
          <div style="flex 1; background-color:white; height:100%;width:100%">a</div>
        </div>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why? How do I fix this in Chrome?

Comment: Doesn't have to do with flex, you are setting 100% height on your root div, which is the same as the viewport height. Any children with 100% height also get the viewport height, so they are extending past the bottom of the window. There are simpler ways to achieve the layout it appears you are after.

Comment: First of all add : to your style "flex: 1". Also add prefixes and see the result.

Comment: *Syntax error:* Not sure this is the source of your problem, but start with fixing this: `<div style="flex 0 0 auto;`

Comment: Ah, I see. So the answer to this question is that #1: 100% height and width should only be on the top level div and #2: I should be more careful formatting my CSS. Thanks!